# Equivalency of three statements about localization of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to show that these are equivalent for any ring $R$:

1. For every prime ideal $P\subset R $, $R_P $ is a domain, where $R_P=\{r/s : r\in R , s\in R-P \}$.
2. For every maximal ideal $m\subset R$, $R_m$ is a domain.
3. If $ab=0$, then $\mathrm{Ann}(a)+\mathrm{Ann}(b)=R$, where $\mathrm{Ann}(a)=\{x\in R: xa=0\}$.

I tried to derive $3$ from $2$, but I could just prove $\mathrm{Ann}(a)+m=R $, when $m$ is a maximal ideal contains $\mathrm{Ann}(b)$.

If ring is commutative, $1$ gives $2$ trivially.

Is there any hint? 
Thanks

Comment: 2. $\Rightarrow$ 3. Suppose  $\mathrm{Ann}(a)+\mathrm{Ann}(b)\ne R$, and $m$ a maximal ideal containing  $\mathrm{Ann}(a)+\mathrm{Ann}(b)$. From $ab=0$ you get $a/1=0/1$ or $b/1=0/1$ in $R_m$, that is, there is $s\in R\setminus m$ such that $sa=0$ or $sb=0$, and you are done.

Comment: @user26857 ok thanks. But how to get 1 from 3?

Comment: I think the essential part to prove 3. --> 1. is to understand the following: If $\frac{a}{s} \neq 0$ in $R_p$, then $\operatorname{Ann}(a) \subset p$.

Comment: @user26857 if $\frac {a}{s},\frac {b}{t}\in R_p$ are nonzero, but their product is zero,we get $Ann (a),Ann (b)\subset p$,also there is a $x\in R-p $ such that $xab=0$,what then?

Comment: @MooS yes $Ann (a)\subset p$,but how to continue?